# How to parse json specific fields using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, json

I'm trying to parse a very simple json object with 1 value. (ocUnit test below)

```
- (void) testHatCartParseWithValidRefId {
  NSString* data = @"{\"refid\":999}";
  Cart* obj = [HatCartParseJson parseJsonAndReturnObject:data];

  STAssertTrue([obj.refid isEqualToString:@"999"], @"fail");
}
```

In the implementation everything fails when I add the line to pull it from either key or index.  How should I pull this from the json input? Please keep in mind I need this json parse (not string) the actual code I'm working with is a large set of JSON data.

```
+ (Cart *) parseJsonAndReturnObject:(NSString *)json
{ 
  NSArray* cart = [json JSONValue];
  for (NSDictionary* item in cart) {
    Cart* obj = [[Cart alloc] init];
    //NSString* refid = [item objectAtIndex:0];
    //NSString* refid = [item objectForKey:@"refid"];
    [obj setRefid:@"999"];

    return obj;
  }

  return nil;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting that the return value of `JSONValue` is an `NSArray`, which in this case it isn't.

So, you must do a check if the return value is actually an `NSArray`, and if it is, then iterate through the collection, otherwise check if it's an `NSDictionary`, and if it is, then return the `Cart` object with the `refid` from the `NSDictionary`. If all of this fails, then just return `nil`.

As a side point, according to Apple's [Object Ownership Policy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html), you should return `autorelease`-d objects from methods whose names do not contain the words "alloc", "new" or "copy". This would be one such method where you'd return an `autorelease`-d object.

```
+ (Cart *) parseJsonAndReturnObject:(NSString *)json
{ 
  id cart = [json JSONValue];
  NSString* refid = nil;
  if([cart isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    refid = [[cart objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"refid"];
  } else if([cart isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    refid = [cart objectForKey:@"refid"];
  }

  if(refid) {
    Cart* c = [[Cart alloc] init];
    [c setRefid:refid];
    return [c autorelease];
  } 
  return nil;
}
```

Comment: @Toran Also, if `cart` is an `NSArray`, will there ever be more than one element?

Comment: currently only a single element - would it make a difference?

Comment: @Toran Yes, if there was more than one element, what would you return?